# Order of elements in a group of order $2^a p^b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

A Group $G$ is called an EPO-group if every element of $G$ has prime order. Let $G$ be a group of order $2^a p^b$ ($a,b\geq 1$, $p$ an odd prime) with $Z(G)=1$. Suppose that $G$ is not an EPO-group. Can we find four elements of different orders in $G$? We know that $G$ is solvable and there are an element of order 2 and an element of order $p$ in $G$. What can we say anymore about $G$?

Comment: Well yes. There is also the identity element plus some element not of prime order, so that is $4$.

Comment: Sorry I mean elements except identity. Is it possible to determine the order of 2 other elements (If they exist).

Comment: Then clearly not, as exemplified by the $a=b=1$ case.

Comment: But the case $a=b=1$ would be an EPO-group. In a dihedral group of order $2p^2$, the only orders are $1,2,p,p^2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ahh, woops. Missed the part about trivial center.

Comment: @DerekHolt Did it true for other orders except $2p^2$?

Comment: Whenever $p|(q-1)$, there is a group of order $pq^2$ (a Frobenius group)  in which the element orders are $\{1,p,q,q^2\}$. Also note that the element orders in $S_4$ are $\{1,2,3,4\}$.